# Trim first two characters from year of GETDATE()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I am trying to create a WHERE clause that says

```
WHERE column_1 = TRIM(LEADING '20' FROM(DATEPART(year, GETDATE())))
```

Basically `column_1` contains the fiscal year but the fiscal year is in the database as  8 or 9 not 2008 or 2009.

So I need to figure a way to trim off at least the `'20'` so that the query will run correctly... The more dynamic the better because I need to set this up to run in an SSIS pkg and the less hard coding the better.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on the datatype of the column_1

print right(datepart(year,getdate()),2) --string with leading zero
print convert(int,right(datepart(year,getdate()),2))--int

**EDIT**

based on @Richard's answer
print datepart(year,getdate()) % 100

Comment: You beat me to it! Hey Jon, what mike said! :P

Answer (score 6):

Rather than trim, use modulus:

```
...
WHERE column_1 = (YEAR(GETDATE()) % 100)
```

Comment: I like the % 100 idea, but that is not T-SQL and will not work in a sql server where clause

Comment: @mike: This is perfectly valid T-SQL.

Comment: @mike: Your comment was referring to the %, not to the "==", which is very obviously a typo and no reason to down-vote.

Comment: @mike: I explicitly checked that it is (SQL Server 2005 BOL at least).

Comment: @Tomalak, I said "I like the % 100 idea", however I can see your point that it is not clear.  I was referring to the "where clause", should have said the "==" is not T-SQL. I did not down vote. @Richard, +1, I like your answer best, YEAR() is nicer than DATEPART()

Comment: YEAR + a modulus will execute faster than converting to string then taking only last 2 chars.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a convert format that will only print the last 2 digits of the year?

Answer (score 0):

If your column is guaranteed to refer to years >= 2000 and < 2100, then you would get away with the rather obvious:

```
SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()) - 2000
```

But... Honestly, it would make me weep to see such code in a production environment. That's just a bit too much WTF, imo.